# Having an issue with Wait till element present functionality in Selenium Web driver 2.44.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am facing an issue with random behaviour for element wait/present/clickable. I have used below logic to wait for that element but its working some times and does not working some other times. Can some one please help me how to solve this issue with generic/standard way of element wait.

Issue/Requirement : I have to wait for an element till its present/clickable while loading web page. I am using Selenium Web driver 2.44.0 and Firefox 33.0.3

Logic used :

```
package com.ericsson.testing.automation.framework.ui.common;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class Test {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static long timeOut = 180000;
    /** The poll time. */
    public int pollTime = 100;

    public void isElementClickable(WebDriver driver, WebElement webelement,
            long timeOutForEachElement) {
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,
                    timeOutForEachElement);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webelement));
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException ex) {
            // Some debug logging info
        }
    }

    // Senario 2
    public void waitTillElementPresent(WebElement webelement) {
        System.out.println("Before Fluent Wait");
        System.out.println("Xpath = " + webelement);
        FluentWait<WebElement> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebElement>(
                webelement);
        fluentWait.pollingEvery(pollTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        fluentWait.withTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("After Fluent Wait");
        fluentWait.until(new Function<WebElement, Boolean>() {

            public Boolean apply(WebElement webelement) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("inside isDisplayed check");
                    return webelement.isDisplayed();
                } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Inside NoSuchElementException");
                    return false;
                } catch (ElementNotVisibleException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Inside ElementNotVisibleException");
                    return false;
                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Inside StaleElementRefException");
                    return false;
                } catch (UnhandledAlertException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Inside UnhandledAlertException");
                    // Some logic for debug logging
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Senario 3
    public void clickOnElement(String element) {
        while (true) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(element)).click();
            System.out.println("Trying to click on element" + element);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Clicked on element" + element);
    }

    /*
     * private boolean isElementPresent(String element) {
     *                  int myLink
     *  =driver.findElements(By.xpath(element)).size();
     *                  if (myLink != 0)                      return true;
     *                  else                      return false;              }
     */

    // Senario 4
    public void waitTillElementisClicked(String element) {
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag == true) {
            // driver.findElement(By.xpath(element)).click();
            // flag=driver.findElement(By.xpath(element)).isSelected();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(element)).click();
            // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(element)).isSelected()) {
                flag = false;
                System.out.println("element already clicked");
            }

            // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("trying to click the element");
        }
        System.out.println("Clicking the element");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try "**driver.findElement(By.xpath(element)).size()>0**". With my experience if you are doing everything correct still facing element issue, this works.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the scenario?

Comment: You possibly mean `.findElements()` because a `.size()` call on a single element is going to throw an error.

Comment: in this case I could not able to conver the webelement to string. how can i convert this webelement to string(Error : The method xpath(String) in the type By is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)). if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(homePage.homeButton())).size()>0){
homePage.homeButton().click();
   }

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the scenario? –  Albin Joseph.

Comment: @AlbinJoseph-Could you please provide more information about the scenario? –  I am waiting for an element in my page. Depends on load of the page it may take 2 to 50 Seconds. But I can not wait till 50 Seconds every time implicitly. So I want to write a method wait till element loads/present/clickable. As I mentioned in my question I used few scenarios but its not working for my Selenium version(2.44.0). Would like to know "Is there is any generic API method to solve my issue?" or is this is the problem with my selenium version

Answer (score 0):

```
Though the size() works for webelements, you could pass your single element in the locator
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
        {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) 
            {
                return verifyWebElementListIsPresent(se.driver().findElements(locator));
            }
        });   
 public boolean verifyWebElementListIsPresent(List<WebElement> element)
    {
        List<WebElement> adminPermissions = element;
        if (adminPermissions.size() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Element is displayed on the page");
            return true;    
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element is not displayed on the page");
            return false;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static WebElement elementExists(String xpath){
        // make sure driver is available to this method..
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2); //Increase wait time if required                                                                               
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
            System.out.println("Element having xpath - "+xpath+" is present!");
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));  
        }catch(ElementNotFoundException e1){
            System.out.println("Element having xpath - "+xpath+" is not present!");
            return null;
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Element having xpath - "+xpath+" is not present!");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

- WebElement xyz = elementExists(pass xpath string);
- If web element is found, it will return web element, else it will return null.
- If web element is present also check **whether its displayed** for use.
  webelement.isDisplayed() should return true.